# Ошибка на IPhone из-за slider swiper "на странице ... повторно возникла проблема"

Tags: ios, swiper.js

У меня на сайте есть слайдер реализован через swiper, слайдер включается только на разрешение 1024

```
    var width = window.innerWidth
    if (width < 1024) {
        newnewswiper = new Swiper('.slider_mega', {
            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
            },
            speed: 1500,
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            observeSlideChildren: true,
        });
    }
})
```

Выглядит это примерно вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Везде отображается хорошо, кроме IPhone.
На IPhone когда спускаешься до  данного слайдера и пытаешь перелистнуть слайдер, страница перезагружается, а на второй раз выдает вот такую ошибку "на странице ... повторно возникла проблема"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста